# VB Net chart series: data points disappear results in line gaps after series disable and enable

Tags: vb.net, charts

I have a line chart that is data bound to a data table.  It plots fine but data points disappear after a series is disabled and enabled.  Gaps also result in the plot.

The series is disabled/enabled from a list box to allow the user to filter onto a specific series.

I have attempted to insert empty points into the initial charting and after the disable/enable but there is no change.

Here are some code snippets (I attempted to post images but need a reputation of 10):

```
' *** Initial plotting ***
With chrt.Series(index)
    .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    .Points.DataBind(dtParamOutput.Select("VEH_ID = " & vInfoItem.vehID & " AND PARAM_NAME = '" & paramList.Item(indexParam) & "'", "EVENT_TIME ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows), "EVENT_TIME", "PARAM_VALUE", Nothing)
    .BorderWidth = 2

' *** Attempt at inserting empty data points with initial plotting ***
    If paramList.Item(indexParam).ToString = "Parameter1" Then
        ' *** Tried interval of Days, Hours, Minutes ***
        chrt.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Hours, chrt.Series(index))
        .EmptyPointStyle.BorderWidth = 2
        ' *** Set to black dashed line to differentiate for now; prefer same as non-empty points ***
        .EmptyPointStyle.BorderColor = Color.Black
        .EmptyPointStyle.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash
    End If
End With

' *** Disabling all series ***
For i As Integer = 0 To lbVeh.Items.Count - 1
    .Series(i).Enabled = False
Next

' *** Enable selected series based on user selection in list box ***
With chrt
    For Each selectedVeh In lbVeh.SelectedItems
        .Series(selectedVeh).Enabled = True
        ' *** Tried interval of Days, Hours, Minutes
        .DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, IntervalType.Hours, selectedVeh)
        .Series(selectedTools).EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Black
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my own problem, caused by me.  After data binding the chart series and data table, I needed the max and min values from the series for auto scaling and other analysis.

So I used the following to get the min and max value.

```
chrt.Series(index).Points.Min
chrt.Series(index).Points.Max
```

What I realized looking at the charts is that all my min and max values disappeared in that series after running the above.  Without the min and max values, gaps would appear in my plots.  I did not think that getting the min and max values would remove it from the series.